# Typo3v11 site configuration https results in 404

Tags: typo3

we have a running page with Typo3 v9.5 and switched to Typo3 v11.
There is a big problem with the Site Configuration. If we set the Entry Point to protocol https we got 404 errors on all pages. If we set the protocol to http it works as expected also with https://.

In front of the Apache we have a HAProxy which unpack the https and redirect the queries to a varnish proxy and the varnish redirects to Apache Servers (more than one).

One more problem with this http Entry Point is that a call to https://mypage/typo3/ results in a redirect to insecure http://mypage/typo3/ which will not be accepted.

What I have to change so that the Entry Point uses https protocol and an access to my pages do not result in 404 errors?

Comment: Have you configured any of the`$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['reverseProxy*']` settings?

Comment: @julian-hofmann thanks for the tip. But it seams not to work as expected. I added `        'reverseProxyIp' => '10.221.0.29,10.221.0.30,172.18.0.3', 'reverseProxyHeaderMultiValue' => 'last',
'reverseProxySSL' => '*',` to my LocalConfiguration.php in 'SYS' and change the site-configuration of base: to https instead of http. The result when open a page is Typo3 error 404, no site-configuration found.  10.221.0.X are HAProxies, the 172.18.0.3 is a Varnish cache. In Varnishlog I see x-forwarded-for: a.b.c.d, 173.18.0.3 therefore multivalue is 'last'. Maybe reverseProxySSL must be 'none'.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @julian-hofmann for the tip again.

In our environment I need the following settings in the AdditionalConfiguration.php

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['reverseProxySSL'] = '*';

# there is more than one reverseProxyIP
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['reverseProxyIP'] = '*';

# removes from http header x_forwarded_for the last entry (proxy)
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['reverseProxyHeaderMultiValue'] = 'last';
```

And have to set the http header variable x_forwarded_proto to https also.

Now it works as expected.